# get the lat,lng from the geocoder json result

Tags: jquery, google-geocoder

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   hangout = results[0].geometry.location;
   console.log(hangout);
   console.log(hangout.lat);
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong here but what is it? hangout alerts the lat lng but how do i get the lat by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng

You would use:

```
hangout.lat()
```